# Using <cfinclude> with this.mapping

Tags: coldfusion, mapping, coldfusion-9, application.cfc

In my application I have a header and footer include. In my Application.cfc I've set up a function that names my application and sets mapping.

```
<cfcomponent output="no">
<cfset this.name = "thesitename">
<cfset this.datasource = "thesitedatasource">
<cfset this.rootDir = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) />
<cfset this.mappings = structNew()>
<cfset this.mappings["/planning"] =  "#this.rootDir#planning/" />
<cfset this.mappings["/images"] = "#this.rootDir#images/" />
<cfset this.mappings["/includes"] = "#this.rootDir#includes/" />
<cfset this.mappings["/js"] = "#this.rootDir#js/" />
<cfset this.mappings["/portfolio"] = "#this.rootDir#portfolio/" />
</cfcomponent>
```

If I have a page in a subdirectory like this: `planning/index.cfm` the `<cfinclude>` can't locate anything in the images folder when I use the following path: `<li class="imagelink"><img src="/images/facebook.png"></li>`

Pages in the root directory don't have a problem.

If I understand correctly, the problem has to do with the mapping doesn't take place prior to the include being called, or something like that... How do I get the mapped paths to work properly in my include?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ColdFusion mappings are completely separate from a web server 'alias' or 'virtual directory'.  In order for your code to work, you will need to add a web server mapping, 'alias' in Apache or 'virtual directory' in IIS, named 'images' that points to the directory where you keep the images.

The 'images' ColdFusion mapping will only work in ColdFusion - for example, when creating an object, you could use createObject( "component", "images.image") (assuming of course that you had a CFC named Image in that diectory.

Comment: So, essentially, there's no way to use this.mapping and have the cfinclude work properly. So, what type of coding makes use of the `(./images)` syntax?

Comment: You can use cfinclude to include ColdFusion files that may be in the 'images' directory, but when you specify the src attribute of the img tag, that is telling the web browser where to look for the file - and the web browser has no knowledge (nor should it) of ColdFusion mappings. The easy fix to your problem is to create an 'alias' if on Apache or a 'virtual directory' if on IIS named 'images' that points to the folder where the images are stored..it will then 'just work'